# Should i use JQuery's load method for my website, as Google does not see content loaded from this method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, seo

I have a wesite http://govtjobs.hitechstudent.com.
In this website i have a HTML template, and in this template i used JQuery's load() method which after html loading, access a PHP Script which puts data in HTML skeleton. My Problem is it that google does not see the content loaded from PHP script, so nothing gets crawled. What should i do? Is there any other better approach i should use instead of mine.
Java Script Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#govtjobs').load("resources/script/govtJobProvider.php);
    });
```

Please Help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Maybe but think a little harder and you will find that it is also related to javascript and HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this post: http://seogadget.com/javascript-framework-seo/

In any case make you site fully crawleable is a very hard work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX for this purpose , here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
           url: "resources/script/govtJobProvider.php",
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "html",
           success: function(html) 
           {
               //here you have complete response in **html**
               $("html").html(html);
           }
      });//end ajax call
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most crawlers, including Google simply ignore and don't run Scripts. Therefor it's no wonder that Google can not find the content loaded from an ajax function.

Maybe you can do:

- add more keywords to your head according to content of your govtJobProvider.php
- hidden div containing stuff (pretty dirty and idk if crawlers ignore these contents)
- simply don't use ajax for content that should be crawled
- etc.

Sorry, cant catch more of em atm *coffee*.
Maybe you can try using this nice article: http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/google.shtml